# How to print a PHP file using PrintJS?

Tags: javascript, php, printjs

I'm having a problem wherein I want to use PrintJS library in PHP. I created a PHP file which is invoice.php that is what I want to print out as a PDF using the library. I also created a JavaScript function in which I call the printJS function. How can I able to view the PHP file as a PDF using JavaScript

This is my invoice.php in which I want to print out using the JavaScript function in which I added the printJS function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
<title>VShip Invoice</title>
```

```
<style>
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
}

.invoice {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}

.invoice td,
th {
    padding: 8px;
    border-left: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-right: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.invoice td {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.invoice th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

input {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
}

/* .container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
} */
```

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div>
                <img src="<?= base_url('assets/images/vivmo-logo.png') ? 
           >" alt="logo" style="width:180px;" class="logo-default" />
            </div>
            <div style="line-height:0.4;">
                <p>5730 Roseville Rd, Sacramento, CA 95842</p>
                <p>+1 844 90 VIVMO(844-908-4866)</p>
                <p>support@vivmo.co</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Logo -->

        <!-- Bill Information Heading -->
        <div style="padding-top:15px;">
            <!-- Bill To -->
            <div style="float:left;padding-left:30px;">
                <div>
                    <h3 style="font-weight:800;margin-top:18px;margin- 
   bottom:0px;">Bill To:</h3>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:-10px;">
                    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Client's Name</h4>
                    <div style="line-height:0.4;margin-top:-8px;">
                        <p>5730 Roseville Rd</p>
                        <p>Sacramento, CA 95842</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Bill To -->

            <!-- Bill Invoice Number -->
            <div style="float:right;">
                <div style="background-color:#d3d3d3;padding:1px 61px 1px 10px;">
                    <h3 style="font-family:'Open Sans';color:#fff;margin-top:8px;margin-bottom:8px;font-size:1.5em;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">INVOICE #0001</h3>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-left:25%;">
                    <p style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:13.5px;font-weight:500;">Date: 10-12-2022</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Bill Invoice Number -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Bill Information Heading -->
        <br>
        <!-- Bill Information Table -->
        <div style="margin-top:18%;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
            <table class="invoice">
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Apple iPhone 6S 16GB</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">2</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">$999</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="border-bottom:2px solid #d3d3d3;">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- End Bill Information Table -->

        <!-- Bill Information Total -->
        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
            <div style="float:left;background-color:#d3d3d3;width:50%;">
                <div style="text-align:center;padding-top:13%;padding-bottom:13%;">
                    <h3 style="color:#fff;font-family:'Open Sans';font-size:1.6em;padding-left:16%;padding-right:16%;">THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;padding-right:30px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;padding-top:8px;">Subtotal</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;">Discount</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;">Subtotal Less Discount</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;">Tax Rate(%)</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;">Total Tax</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-family:'Open Sans';float:right;font-size:13px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;">Shipping/Handling</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="$999" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <hr style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
                </table>
                <div style="float:left;margin-left:30%;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0px;font-family:'Open Sans';">Total</h3>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top:0px;font-family:'Open Sans';font-weight:800;">$999,000</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Bill Information Total -->

        <!-- Billing Terms and Instruction -->
        <div style="margin-top:33%;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3 style="font-size:15px;">Terms & Instruction</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
                <div style="padding:18px;">
                    <p style="font-size:13px;">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum fugit quaerat quos cupiditate soluta? Quasi voluptatibus debitis consequuntur asperiores saepe.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Billing Terms and Instruction -->

        <!-- Billing Footer -->
        <div style="background-color:#d3d3d3;margin-top:30px;">
            <div>
                <div style="padding:1px 30px;">
                    <h5 style="color:#fff;font-family:'Raleway';font-weight:500;">vivmo.co</h5>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Billing Footer -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the function in which I add the PrintJS function to print the PHP file

```
function print_invoice()
{
 printJS({
        printable: base_url + "shipment/invoice",
        type: 'pdf',
        targetStyles: ['*']
    })
}
```

Comment: "_How can I able to view the PHP file as a PDF using JavaScript_" Are you trying to print a PHP page or are you asking how to convert a PHP page to PDF?

Comment: I'm trying to print a PHP page using PrintJS library

Answer (score 0):

```js
      function getFileAndPrint() {
        // Generate pdf and get its filename  
        // Assuming your are writing this in a .php file  
        let printFile = '<?php echo $variable; ?>'  
    
        // Freedom to do anything else you may want to
        // ...
    
        // Pass pdf to printJS
        printJS(printFile)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this way

```
function print_invoice() {
    printJS({
        printable: "<?php echo base_url; ?>" + "shipment/invoice.php",
        type: 'pdf',
        targetStyles: ['*']
    })
}
```